# Multiple labels not printing in ZEBRA printer

Tags: android, sdk, zebra-printers

I am integrating Zebra printer SDK into Android application, I want to print same label multiple times which is sent to printer, only single time label is printing. I am using code as per follows but not working label printing only single time:

```html
^XA,^LH20,30^FS,^FO5,0^A0,35,35^FDitemLookupCode^FS,^FO5,30^A0N,36,32^FDdescription^FS,^FO5,60^BY4^BC,80,N^FD>;>itemLookupCode^FS,^FO390,75^A0N,87,62^FD^FS,^FO5,150^A0N,36,32^FDsubDescription^FS,^PQ2,^XZ
```

Also I tried to use at the end of the code for multiple quantities but not worked

```html
^PQ2,0,1,Y,^XZ
^PQ2,0,1,N,^XZ
```

Comment: Can you share your android code as well? the ZPL looks like it should work for printing the label twice.

Comment: hey it's working perfectly now the one which I added firstly code.